# iFrame - prevent link to open in new window

Tags: javascript, wpf, iframe, browser

I have a WPF application with a WebBrowser control that run a web application that will be displayed in full screen.

In the application, I have a iFrame used to display an other website (could be any website...). But I would like to prevent this website to open a new window when a link is clicked and prevent any dialog window to appear.

Is there a way to do it ? I have no control on these websites source code...

Comment: You might want to look into [HTML5 Sandboxing](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#sandboxing); apart from that there’s little you can do to restrict functionality of a 3rd party page.